# Как корректно отобразить переменную double в java

Tags: java, консоль, double

При нахождении скорости целыми числами вывод отображается корректно, но если задать, допустим время 7,6 , то компилятор пишет ошибку

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Speed {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Давай-ка посчитаем твою скорость");
    System.out.println("Введи время и дистанцию");
    System.out.println("Введи дистанцию в метрах");

    double distance = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Хорошо, теперь время");
    double time = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("");
    double speed = ((distance/time)*3600/1000);
    double speed1 = (distance/time); 
    System.out.format("Твоя скорость равна ");
    System.out.format("%.2f", speed);
    System.out.println(" км/ч");
    System.out.print("или ");
    System.out.format("%.2f", speed1);
    System.out.print(" м/с");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следует задать время через точку: например, `7.6`

Кроме того, можно настроить локаль, чтобы можно было задавать время через запятую, но это, как говорится, совсем другая история.